# Longer flashing of search string during multi-file searches

Tags: display, xref

When the cursor is in the `*xref*` buffer, following `dired-do-find-regexp`, the found string in the adjacent frame flashes, but too briefly, making it quite hard to see.

A simple solution is to increase the duration of the pulse of the found string.

The code goes through the following functions in xref.el(.gz):

(On macOS: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/progmodes/xref.el.gz`)

- xref-next-line
- xref-show-location-at-point
- xref--show-location
- xref--show-pos-in-buf
- xref-after-jump-hook
- xref-pulse-momentarily
- pulse-momentary-highlight-region

and the calls continue in pulse.el.gz:

(on macOS: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/cedet/pulse.el.gz`)

- pulse-momentary-highlight-region
- pulse-momentary-highlight-overlay

It would be enough to increase `pulse-delay`

```
defcustom pulse-delay .03
```

but that doesn't change the pulse time.

How can I increase the duration of the pulse?

This is a [sequel](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36565/3922) question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug or an enhancement request. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, please consider filing a bug report / enhancement request, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq pulse-delay 0.09)
```

works for me, and really increases the duration of the pulse. The problem is likely in how you change that value.

Answer (score 0):

Beside `pulse-delay` there is the option `pulse-iterations`. The default for `pulse-iterations` is `10` (which is quite low). Increase it to your liking. I've tried `100` which slows down the pulse considerably.

(emacs-version: 25.1.50)